# onPress event in navigationOptions property

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a menu button in the header area of one of my screens.

However, I can't figure out how to get the onPress navigation to work.

Obviously, the code below will produce an error because navigate is defined after it's first used.

But, when I try to move the const { navigate } declaration up before I set the navigationOptions property, I get an "unexpected token" error in my IDE (visual studio code).

Is there any way around this?

Thanks!

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component
 {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
}
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Seekers',
            headerRight: 
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => navigate('Menu', { 
                    menu: options
                })}>
                    <Image source={require('./images/menu.png')} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
                </TouchableHighlight>,
};

render() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
            <View>
            ... more view stuff...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizing the header changed in the last few updates of React Native and passing navigation options changed too. According to the doc [Screen Navigation Options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options#Two-Ways-to-specify-each-option), Dynamic configuration is possible and the 'navigationOptions' now can be used as a function which takes navigation Options as parameters.

For example, I wanted a button to close and open my DrawerNavigator in the header. In my `router.js`file, I wrote:

```
export const Root = StackNavigator({
    App: {
        screen: AppDrawer,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            headerLeft: <BurgerMenu nav = {navigation} />,
        })
    }
}, {
    headerMode: 'screen',
});
```

In your case, I think you should declare your navigationOptions as a function:

```
static navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: 'Seekers',
    headerRight: <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () =>
                     navigation.navigate('Menu', { menu: options })}>
                     <Image source={require('./images/menu.png')} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
                 </TouchableHighlight>,
};
```

I didn't personnally try to set navigationOptions from the component itself. Instead I declare the options in my StackNavigator.

Let me know if it works !

## EDIT

#### How does my navigation work ?

For the navigation side of my application I'm simply using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/).

It would be pretty long to copy all the content of my files here so I created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/FreddyPoly/a6c1d4a2b76c526055373d830552bc82) for you to see how I implemented that.

**First,** I create a `router.js` file, in which I define my screens and the type of navigation ([here](https://gist.github.com/FreddyPoly/a6c1d4a2b76c526055373d830552bc82#file-router-js)). Focus on the variable named `Root`, this is my main StackNavigator. This is the entry point of my app.

**Second,** I edited the `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` so they both render the same component.

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/index';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('obexto_expensemanager', () => App);
```

**Third.** What does my App component contains ? This component is the one I use to render my entry point defined in the `router.js`. What is important in this file is:

```
import { Root } from './config/router';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Root />
        )
    }
}
```

I use the StackNavigator defined in `router.js` as my main component for my app.

**Why ?** I like the way this navigation works because you separate clearly your stacks from your components. And all your navigation is set in a single file. So, in your project you'll have your `scene` folder with all your components and a `router` where you connect them.

In my example I wanted to add a button in my header so I could open my DrawerNavigator. The header can be accessed from the `navigationOptions` when you define your Navigator, that's why I defined the option `headerLeft` in my App StackNavigator, so it's visible in every screen.

I don't know if this is clear for you but don't hesitate to tell me if it's not and what is still obscur to you. I'll do my best to help !

Comment: What is BurgerMenu?  What component(s) does it use?  Thanks!

Comment: How did you declare it in your stackNavigator?  I tried moving it there, but I get an 'undefined' error on: this.props.navigation

Comment: BurgerMenu is just a component I defined. Basically it's an image wrapped in a TouchableOpacity so I can open my Drawer Navigator. I'll edit my answer to explain how my navigation works. Sorry for responding so late !

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, how about declaring the `navigationOptions` directly on the StackNavigator (assuming that's what you are using). For example

`

```
const Nav = StackNavigator({yourRoutes}, {
{
  navigationOptions: {...}
}
});
```

`